# How can I prevent background misalignment?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a webpage. I am using buttons, but unfortunately there is a "bar" that ruins my background image. You can see this on the red "Star".

[image: bar ruins star]

How can i fix this bar through my background image?

Comment: Please supply basic code to reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background image you're using isn't meant to be tiled. Either choose one that is or use `background-size: cover;` to achieve the look you want.

Comment: awesome, background-size cover worked :) Thanks a lot